# What is the best way to mnt azure storage account so that all notebooks inside azure databricks can access gen2 container

Tags: azure-databricks

Run the following in your notebook to authenticate and create a mount point.

```
 configs = {"fs.azure.account.auth.type": "OAuth",
            "fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type":      
       "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider",
              "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id": "<application-id>",
              "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret": 
 dbutils.secrets.get(scope="<scope-name>",key="<service-credential-key-name>"),
              "fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint": 
              "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<directory-id>/oauth2/token"}
```

Optionally, you can add  to the source URI of your mount point.

```
     dbutils.fs.mount(
   source = "abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/",
     mount_point = "/mnt/<mount-name>",
  extra_configs = configs)
```

Do i have to write this code in all notebooks? or in only one notebook and call it ?

or can i add this code in databricks cluster, so that when i cluster starts it will mount ?

storage-account-name is different in uat and prod . so how do i pass the different  storage-account-name  in uat and prod ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mount operation should be done once, for example, from the interactive notebook (you can do it with [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/mount) as well). After that, everyone inside the workspace will have access to that mount - that's one of the reasons why mounting is declared as deprecated.

The more secure way would be to adopt the [Unity Catalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/) - it provides better access control.  If you can't do it right now, then the recommended way would be to use [cluster-scoped credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/storage/azure-storage#azureserviceprincipal) and access data using the `abfss` URL. (You can put these credentials into a cluster policy to simplify their configuration on many clusters/jobs).